# Where do I download Android build tools?

Tags: android-sdk-tools

I tried using the command line tools but it just says "dependant package with key emulator not found" and I also tried searching up "Android SDK build tools" and "Android build tools" but nothing showed up. Does anyone have a download link / copy of those build tools?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download "Android SDK" or "Android Build Tools" through command line than first of all you have to download the "Android Command line tools" from the Android Studio. Here is the link for that - [Download Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads)
and than you have to make changes in the "environment variable" and after that you can download the "SDK Packages" through command line with this command.

> sdkmanager --install